# M2 - Mass mailing reset password email

Tags: email, password, user, forgot-password

I want to send all the user the reset password email, we have over 6000 user so it can't be done by hand.

I found this script from this website:

```
    <?php 
    //place this before any script you want to calculate time
    $time_start = microtime(true);

    // MAGENTO START
    include('app/bootstrap.php');

    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement;

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $_customers = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface');
    $customerCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection');
    $customerCollection->load();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($customerCollection as $customers) {

        $email = $customers->getData('email');

        try {
                $_customers->initiatePasswordReset($email, AccountManagement::EMAIL_RESET);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                // Do nothing, we don't want anyone to use this action to determine which email accounts are registered.
            } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                echo __('We\'re unable to send the password reset email.');
            }
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $i . " Email :-" . $email . " Mail Sent";
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

But that isn't working :(

Is there a way to make this script work or maybe another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I printed the exception message in the code,

```
 try {
                $_customers->initiatePasswordReset($email, AccountManagement::EMAIL_RESET);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                // Do nothing, we don't want anyone to use this action to determine which email accounts are registered.
            } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                echo __($exception->getMessage());
            }
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $i . " Email :-" . $email . " Mail Sent";
        $i++;
```

I got the error like this `We received too many requests for password resets.`

For this error you need to disable the password protection in magento2 backend customer configuration.

I have disabled password protection from `Configuration -> Customers -> customer configuration`. so it look like this in my admin,

[image]

set the password protection to none and try it. After the password sent, please revert back to original configuration for security purpose

Comment: Hi, I tried the code from you combined with the code I already had, but with no result, even no error or something.

Comment: I did something wrong, now it worked! But I have 2 mail addresses and with one I can't change it, the message is; it couldn't be saved. With the other mail address it worked. Maybe that's because of some protection?

Comment: Is that mail is different from other emails?

Comment: Is look like spam email?

Comment: I have firstname.lastname@gmail.com and firstnamelastname@gmail.com the only difference is the . (It's not marked as spam)

Comment: maybe that mail is not existed or deactivated. Because your code working for all emails except this particular email